# fedora on the asus transformer?

Tags: linux, fedora, laptop, hardware-compatibility

Can you run fedora on the Asus Transformer?  The form factor looks great, battery, having a tablet, etc; also, if/when gnome3 gets all touchy (sorry for the pun there), it'll be perfect for the transformer.  So (back to the question), can it be done? has it been done?

Answer (score 1):

Well, theoretically, yes, it is possible. Several developers have managed to get Ubuntu to run natively on the device. However, I have not yet seen a single dev working to get Fedora to do the same. It is possible, however, that with Fedora having begun building ARM editions that it could be installed without the use of a special tool from a dev. I am not familiar with how stable these are, and I do not know how you would go about doing so.

Personally, I'm holding out for the Prime, and I'm hoping Fc17 will support ARM well enough that I'll be able to do that install on my own.

Regardless, we'll see.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question is multiple years old, but the current Fedora (28) installs just fine out of the box and is usable with minimal tweaking.